# Run and stop buttons implementation

Tags: jquery

I want to call the function `interpret_st()` when i click `run` and stop `interpret_st` current execution when i click `stop`. Is this the right way to do it?

```
        var interpret_st;
        $('#run').click(function(e) {
            interpret_st = setTimeout(interpret(), 1);
        });

        $('#stop').click(function(e) {
            clearTimeout(interpret_st);
        });
```

**UPDATE** what i really wanted to do is when i clicked stop, i want to go out the function interpret

Comment: Remove the empty parenthesis after the function name in `setTimeout` - that makes it run the function immediately.

Comment: yes its possible, what you wanna actual do with this???

Comment: what i really wanted to do is when i clicked stop, i want to go out the function interpret

Comment: You can't cancel a function once you've started it.  Your script will run in a single thread so nothing can even tell it to stop.

Comment: @archer: thanks. I should do the going out of the loop thing inside my function then right?

Answer (score 1):

Almost :

- you have bad parenthesis (unless `interpret` is a function factory, of course)
- as the second argument is a number of millisecondes, you might prefer to use something like 10000 rather than 1

Here's a fixed code :

```
    var interpret_st;
    $('#run').click(function(e) {
        interpret_st = setTimeout(interpret, 10000);
    });

    $('#stop').click(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(interpret_st);
    });
```

Comment: Please recommend that he not run the function every millisecond! ;)

Comment: @Archer That's because you're old. Young coders are able to do a lot of things in a millisecond, like decide that finally they'd rather cancel that task they just launched.